# 【対する】と【への】はどう違いますか。

Tags: word-choice

to explain some pattern to a friend, I used this sentence :

> 君への気持ちは強くなる。

To express "*my feelings toward you are getting stronger*" and then I thought about 【対する】.

What would the difference between those two sentences below be? :

> 君への気持ちは強くなる。
>
> 君に対する気持ちは強くなる。

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular context, 「対{たい}する」 and 「への」 are interchangeable as far as meaning goes.

「対する」, with the "sharp" Sino 「たい」, sounds a little stiffer (and slightly more formal) than the "softer" Yamato 「への」.

In a short and single sentence like this, however, the difference seems quite minimal.

Note: Though this was not asked about, one ***cannot*** replace 「への」 by「対する」 in the following phrases.

「ハワイ**への**旅{たび}」、「オリンピック**への**道{みち}」、「あなた**への**プレゼント」, etc.